# How to remove '/o' prefix from url in Liferay 7.1

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay-6, liferay-7

In my Liferay 6.2 I had made a module named 'create-user-spring' which is build using spring. In this module I created a method named 'createUser' with request mapping(@RequestMapping(value="/create-user")). 
This is working perfectly in 6.2 when I hit the below url:
'localhost:8080/create-user-spring/service/create-user'.
But in Liferay 7.1 the link outputs 'resource not found'.

When I change the url with 'localhost:8080/o/create-user-spring/service/create-user', it works perfectly. 
Is there any way to remove '/o' from url in Liferay 7.1?
or
Is there any way to use the same url of Liferay 6.2 in 7.1 by mapping or any other way?

Comment: Please check https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/364505 for this and future posts

Answer (score 0):

The `/o` in the URL path is prefix for resources coming from OSGi modules. Much like other similar ones like `/c` and `/portal/layout` for example, [it is hardcoded](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.1.x/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/Portal.java#L93) and can not be easily changed.

What you can do instead is to use a web server in front of the the portal and configure it to proxy `<PUBLIC_HOST>/create-user-spring/*` to `<LIFERAY_HOST>/o/create-user-spring/*`

Comment: can you please elaborate it more ? where I need to configure this proxy ?

Comment: That's up to you. You can use Apache HTTPD or NGINX or lighttpd or HAProxy or whatever works for you.